# How can I select single item from one list and doing operation on all items of second list using Python

Tags: python

For example if I have one list having data , and whose item should be selected one by one

```
a = [0.11 , 0.22 , 0.13, 6.7, 2.5, 2.8]
```

and the other one for which all items should be selected

```
b = [1.2 1.4, 2.6, 2.3, 5.7 9.9]
```

if I select `0.11` from a and do opertation like addition with all the items of b and then save the result in new array or list , how is that br possible with python? ...

I am sorry for the question as I am trying to learn python on my own, kindly tell me how is this thing possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are attempting to do. What is your desired output, and what are you struggling to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Its just an example , which I will implement on my data I just want to know how to use nested for loop ...

Comment: select one item each from a and then do operation on all items of b , then select second item from a and do operation on all items of b ,,, and so on until all the items of a have been selected ....

Comment: Yes, that would entail a loop. What have you tried? What isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You need a *nested loop*. You can do it in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to produce a list of lists:

```
[[item_a + item_b for item_b in b] for item_a in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the end result to be a list of lists it could go like this:

```
c = [[x + y for x in b] for y in a]
```

If you want the end result to be a single list with next sublists appended to each other you could write as such:

```
c=[]
for (y in a):
    c += ([y + x for x in b])
```

Comment: Oh. I was several minutes late as alecxe also answered one way to look at this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert your list into numpy array and then exploit the broadcasting property of numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
npA = np.array(a)
npB = np.array(b)
npA[:, None] + npB

array([[  1.31,   1.51,   2.71,   2.41,   5.81,  10.01],
       [  1.42,   1.62,   2.82,   2.52,   5.92,  10.12],
       [  1.33,   1.53,   2.73,   2.43,   5.83,  10.03],
       [  7.9 ,   8.1 ,   9.3 ,   9.  ,  12.4 ,  16.6 ],
       [  3.7 ,   3.9 ,   5.1 ,   4.8 ,   8.2 ,  12.4 ],
       [  4.  ,   4.2 ,   5.4 ,   5.1 ,   8.5 ,  12.7 ]])
```

You can also do element wise multiplication simply with:

```
npA[:, None] * npB
```

which returns:

```
array([[  0.132,   0.154,   0.286,   0.253,   0.627,   1.089],
       [  0.264,   0.308,   0.572,   0.506,   1.254,   2.178],
       [  0.156,   0.182,   0.338,   0.299,   0.741,   1.287],
       [  8.04 ,   9.38 ,  17.42 ,  15.41 ,  38.19 ,  66.33 ],
       [  3.   ,   3.5  ,   6.5  ,   5.75 ,  14.25 ,  24.75 ],
       [  3.36 ,   3.92 ,   7.28 ,   6.44 ,  15.96 ,  27.72 ]])
```